# API always error 408 - Invalid Data Type Sent

Tags: http, flutter, dart, payment-gateway

I really don't know what happen with this error (I mean by, is this related to the Flutter or Dart or the package that I used or the API that I used). In a nutshell, it always giving me back error code **408 - Invalid data type sent** from my flutter App, while I COMPLETELY could done it in Postman and been tried it with PHP.

I just wanna call a normal POST request to my payment gateway API (I use Midtrans).

---

Here is my result:

**From Postman**

[image: From Postman]

**From my app in Flutter within VS Code**
[image: From my app in Flutter within VS Code]

---

What am I doing wrong? I am completely has no clue about this. 
I will give the detail below for anyone who want to try a simple call to this API so you can reproduce this.

**Endpoint**

`https://api.sandbox.midtrans.com/v2/charge`

**Body**

```
    "payment_type": "bank_transfer",
    "bank_transfer": {
        "bank": "permata",
        "va_number": "1234567890"
    },
    "transaction_details": {
        "order_id": "order-101b-{{2020-11-0222rrd324dzz}}",
        "gross_amount": 44000
    },
    "customer_details": {
        "email": "richie.permana@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "Richie",
        "last_name": "Permana",
        "phone": "+6281 1234 1234"
    },
    "item_details": [
        {
            "id": "item01",
            "price": 21000,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "Schema Programmer"
        },
        {
            "id": "item02",
            "price": 23000,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "Ayam Xoxoxo"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is the header**

```
{
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'authorization':
      'Basic U0ItTWlkLXNlcnZlci1kNnJNbGp5ZDBKSDgyOEhBT28tSWkxM0E=',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache'
}
```

**My Dart Function Snippet**

```
Future _makePayment() async {
    String url = "https://api.sandbox.midtrans.com/v2/charge";

    final Map<String, String> header = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization':
          'Basic U0ItTWlkLXNlcnZlci1kNnJNbGp5ZDBKSDgyOEhBT28tSWkxM0E=',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    };

    var json = jsonEncode({
      "payment_type": "bank_transfer",
      "bank_transfer": {"bank": "permata", "va_number": "1234567890"},
      "transaction_details": {
        "order_id": "order-101b-{{2020-11-0222rrddzz557}}",
        "gross_amount": 44000
      },
      "customer_details": {
        "email": "richie@example.com",
        "first_name": "Richie",
        "last_name": "Permana",
        "phone": "+6281 1234 1234"
      },
      "item_details": [
        {
          "id": "item01",
          "price": 21000,
          "quantity": 1,
          "name": "Schema Programmer"
        },
        {"id": "item02", "price": 23000, "quantity": 1, "name": "Ayam Xoxoxo"}
      ]
    });

    Response response = await post(
      url,
      headers: header,
      body: json,
    );


    var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(
        "payloadddded =>> ${json.runtimeType}\n");
    if (res['status_code'] == 201) {
      print("ngeheeeee berhasil MIDTRAANSS =>> ${res['status_code']}");
    } else {
      print("res full =>> ${response.body}");
      print("ape kaden => ${res['status_code']} || terosz => $res");
    }
  }
```

**Note:**

For the body, you may be need put more attention on the `order_id` because it will return some error if you not change the `order_id` (yes, think it like any other primary key id).

API Docs: https://api-docs.midtrans.com/

---

I really appreciate any helps or workaround given. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart's `package:http` manipulates the `content-type` header under the hood. If it does the encoding from string to bytes for you (i.e. if `body` is a string) then it adds a `charset=xxx` suffix to the content type - it becomes, for example `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Apparently your server is allergic to this. (It shouldn't be, but whatever...). You can prove this using the `dart:io` http client.

```
  var client = HttpClient();
  var request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  request.headers.add(
    'authorization',
    'Basic U0ItTWlkLXNlcnZlci1kNnJNbGp5ZDBKSDgyOEhBT28tSWkxM0E=',
  );
  request.add(utf8.encode(json));
  var response2 = await request.close();
  var reply = await response2.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  print(reply);
  client.close();
```

This gives the same 408 error but does not if the charset suffix is removed.

There's a simple solution. Don't allow `http` to do the encoding for you - do it yourself.

```
  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: headers,
    body: utf8.encode(json),
  );
```

(Your json apparently needs work, because this now complains that the json is invalid, but that's easy to compare with your working postman.)

Comment: I have read the mini-docs from the VS Code autocomplete, it indeed said set the default to `text/plain`. Before, I've been wondered is it my json that has wrong structure but after I found it out, I also start think the main problem, may occur in the header section. Let me check and try your solution. 
Thank you very much for replying.

Comment: You're right. After I encode it myself, it apparently works. Thank you so much. You just saved my life for creating an API just for another API because of this issue.

Maybe this sounds ridiculous but, can you explain to me what's the point of the API being so strict? They don't even not accept any other header (i.e.: `charset=xxx`) And I don't know we supposed to encode it to utf8 in the body?

Comment: It's indicative of a poor API implementation. I don't see anywhere in the document where it even says what encoding to use. Presumably our guess of utf8 is ok. Not allowing the suffix is just poor design.

Comment: Nice answer @RichardHeap